# Why is my Chrome URL bar cookie dialogue different between two profiles?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

On my main profile in Google Chrome 96 (on Linux and Windows) I have "Block all cookies" set in settings. When I go to a site that tries to set cookies, I get a little cookie icon in the URL bar and clicking it produces a "Cookies blocked" or "Cookies set" dialog box that lets me turn cookies on (or off again) for that site, as well as giving me direct options to see the cookies and go to the cookies settings page:

[image: "Cookies blocked" dialog]
[image: "Cookies set" dialog]

I get this same behaviour in incognito mode as well, indicating that this isn't something done by an extension:

[image: Incognito mode]

Using another profile in the exact same version of Chrome (this profile happens to be on Windows) I also have "Block all cookies" enabled, but I get different and much more annoying behaviour. Instead of the "cookie" icon I get an "eye" icon which gives a pop-up with an image of some balloons, rather than any useful functionality, and this only when the site is not allowed to set cookies. (This makes it much more difficult to remove a site's cookies on the fly to reset things.) I also tried creating a new test profile and changing just the cookie setting to "Block all cookies," and got the same result.

[image: balloons dialog]

Presumably I have some other setting that's different between the two profiles, but I've looked around and can't figure out what it might be. How do I get my second profile to work the same way as the first one?

Answer (score 0):

This has been partially fixed in Chrome by version 105. At this point, *all* my profiles are giving the "eye" icon when cookies are blocked, but clicking on "Site not working" now shows a dialogue that now includes the "Show cookies and other site data..." link.

[image: "Site not working?" dialogue]

Clicking that brings up a "Cookies in use" dialogue where you can click on the "Blocked" tab to see a list of domains whose cookies you're not accepting. Selecting a domain and clicking the "Allow" button will add that domain to your whitelist.

The disadvantages that remain as compared to the previous method are:

1. You cannot easily see the list of cookies on sites you've allowed as the "eye" icon does not appear in the URL bar for those.
2. It's a few extra steps now to whitelist cookies for the site in the URL bar.

[image: "Cookies in use" dialogue]